# iPhone Safari "open this page in app store" bypass

Tags: ios, iphone, safari, app-store

I want to make my visitors go directly to App Store without asking if they want to.
In Safari, if the user clicks a link of an app in Apple store, Apple store opens directly without asking. But if I put an HTML auto redirect code, Safari knows somehow that the user doesn't want to opent this link, so it shows to the message: "open this page in app store ".

I tried to do that with Javascript. My idea is making a button click itself:

```
<script>
  setTimeout(
    function() {
            document.getElementById('but').click();
    }, 10000);
</script>
<a href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/facebook/id284882215"><input type="button" value="click me !" id="but" /></a>
```

But unhappily it doesn't work.
How can I do this?

Comment: That's an expected behavior from Safari, which got recently introduced. If you inspect the page, you'll see that this is not a standard alert, so you cannot click it.